How display only selected financial year's budget data and previous financial year's data in single line on line chart in Power BI?
I have financial years like 2022-23, 2023-24, 2024-25, etc., and a financial year slicer. I need to display only the selected financial year's data and the previous financial year's data in a single line.
I have tried dax query also
    SelectedAndPrevYearBudget =
    VAR finyear = SELECTEDVALUE(FinanceDashBoard[FinancialYear])  
    VAR currentStartYear = MID(finyear, 1, 4) 
     VAR currentEndYear = MID(finyear, 6, 2)   


      VAR prevStartYear = FORMAT(VALUE(currentStartYear) - 1, "0000")  
     VAR prevEndYear = FORMAT(VALUE(currentEndYear) - 1, "00")       
    VAR prevYear = prevStartYear & "-" & prevEndYear 

   RETURN
    CALCULATE(
    SUM(FinanceDashBoard[Budget]), 
    FinanceDashBoard[FinancialYear] IN {finyear, prevYear} )


What is you x axis?
